# calculate the number of basic operations in a recursive algorithm

Tags: computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

How can I calculate the number of basic operations (additions and subtractions) in terms of Θ?

```
function F(n)
if n < 1 
    return 1
t <- 0
for i <- 0 to n
    for j <- i to n
        t <- t + j
return t + F(n-1)
```

these are my multiple choices:

Θ(n^2 log n)

Θ(n)

Θ(n^3)

Θ(n^2)

Θ(n^4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are approximately $n$ operations involving $i$.  There are are $n-i$ operations involving $j$.  And we repeat this $n$ times.

Thus, we have something of order $n^3$, since $n\times n\times n=n^3$.

You can also prove by induction that the number of steps involved are

$$f(n)\to\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}6+n$$

Comment: Thank you. The answer is correct but can you explain a little bit more? in the 1st sentence, what do you mean by "And we repeat this n times."? because we have to calculate f(n) of smaller ns?  Second, How did you do the induction?

Comment: @HamidehIraj Yes, we repeat the process because at the end we call $f(n-1)$, so the whole thing starts over again.

Comment: I didn't actually do the induction.  I knew there were $+n$ operations from the "return $t+f(n-1)$" step and $\binom{n-1+3}3=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}6$ other steps due to combinatorics.  (maybe it should also have -1 at the end since we don't call $t+f(n-1)$ when $n=1$...)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how you came up with C(n-1+3,3) in "other steps due to combinatorics"

Comment: @HamidehIraj I 'counted' the number of things that were happening, and 'counting' is akin to 'how many combinations?', hence the C(n,3).$$\text{counting}=\text{number of possible combinations}$$

Comment: by 3 you mean i,j and t?

Comment: Yes, precisely.